# Android Studio Constraint Layout pushing Images offscreen

Tags: android, android-studio, android-layout

So I'm using constraint layout to try and have 4 icon images followed by text at the bottom of my page. Here is an example of the design [Design](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i1MuW.jpg)

When I try to run the app though it shifts the layout offscreen. [Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sxoHh.jpg)

I have everything constrained together, and I'll attach an example [Constraints](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5rb7c.jpg)

Here is the XML design code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".HomeFragment">

<!-- TODO: Update blank fragment layout -->

<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/gradientbackground">


    <ProgressBar

        android:id="@+id/circularProgressbar"
        style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleHorizontal"
        android:layout_width="450dp"
        android:layout_height="450dp"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:indeterminate="false"
        android:max="100"
        android:progress="100"
        android:progressDrawable="@drawable/circle"
        android:secondaryProgress="100"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.496"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />


    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv"
        android:layout_width="250dp"
        android:layout_height="250dp"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="18dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="50%"
        android:textColor="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
        android:textSize="30sp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/circularProgressbar"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="163dp"
        android:text="Steps"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:textSize="80sp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/tv"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="56dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="52dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:src="@drawable/calorie"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/textView3"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.526"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/circularProgressbar"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.453"
        tools:src="@tools:sample/backgrounds/scenic" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="348dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:text="Calories"
        android:textColor="#ffffff"
        android:textSize="25sp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/imageView"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/circularProgressbar"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.463" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView3"
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="56dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:src="@drawable/miles"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/textView3"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/circularProgressbar"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.453"
        tools:src="@tools:sample/backgrounds/scenic" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView4"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:text="Miles"
        android:textColor="#ffffff"
        android:textSize="25sp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.502"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/imageView3"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/circularProgressbar"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.463" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView4"
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="56dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:src="@drawable/score"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/imageView"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.486" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView5"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="52dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:text="Score"
        android:textColor="#ffffff"
        android:textSize="25sp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/imageView4"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView3"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.532" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView5"
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:src="@drawable/bonus"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/textView8"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.527"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/textView5"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/imageView3"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.486" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView8"
        android:layout_width="99dp"
        android:layout_height="41dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="84dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:text="Bonus"
        android:textColor="#ffffff"
        android:textSize="25sp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView4"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.532" />

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Anyone have any ideas on how to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

Check with the below code icons and text are aligned properly (Tested in Nexus 7 and Nexus 6 emulator), make adjustments as per your need.

```
       <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">


    <ProgressBar

        android:id="@+id/circularProgressbar"
        style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleHorizontal"
        android:layout_width="250dp"
        android:layout_height="250dp"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:indeterminate="false"
        android:max="100"
        android:progress="100"
        android:progressDrawable="@drawable/ic_launcher_background"
        android:secondaryProgress="100"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.0" />


    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv"
        android:layout_width="250dp"
        android:layout_height="79dp"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="50%"
        android:textColor="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
        android:textSize="30sp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/circularProgressbar"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:text="Steps"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:textSize="80sp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/circularProgressbar"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/circularProgressbar"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.846"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/circularProgressbar"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.165" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView"
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher_background"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/imageView5"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.181"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/textView4"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/circularProgressbar"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.744" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:text="Calories"
        android:textColor="#000"
        android:textSize="25sp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.333"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/imageView"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/circularProgressbar"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.434" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView3"
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="36dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher_background"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/circularProgressbar"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.43"
        tools:src="@tools:sample/backgrounds/scenic" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView4"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:text="Miles"
        android:textColor="#000"
        android:textSize="25sp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.09"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/imageView3"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/circularProgressbar"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.434" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView4"
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="36dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher_background"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/imageView3" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView5"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="24dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:text="Score"
        android:textColor="#000"
        android:textSize="25sp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/imageView4"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView4"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.531" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView5"
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="52dp"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher_background"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/textView8"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.65"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/textView5" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView8"
        android:layout_width="99dp"
        android:layout_height="41dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="4dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:text="Bonus"
        android:textColor="#000"
        android:textSize="25sp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView3"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.536" />


</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```